# Storing user information across all Angular controllers

Tags: angularjs, authentication, global

I have created an authentication controller which stores authenticated user information using localstorage (I am using ngStorage from Gias Kay Lee). What is the best place (in an Angular way) to access this information in different controllers. I tried using a service, code:

```
myApp.factory("UserService", ["$localStorage", function ($localStorage) {
    var model = {
        IsAuthenticated: $localStorage.IsAuthenticated,
        Username: $localStorage.UserName
    };
    return model;
}]);
```

but this (as the documentation states) behaves as a Singleton.

I also looked at using $rootScope but as far as I can see this can only be initialised in myApp.run. Am I correct?

Of course I could inject ngStorage in every controller but I am curious on how to decouple a dependency on this third party module by creating a custom global function (like the service above).

Related to this above is getting the user information to the $scope:

```
$scope.localStorageToScope = function () {
    $scope.UserName = $localStorage.UserName;
    $scope.UserEmail = $localStorage.UserEmail;
    $scope.UserRole = $localStorage.UserRole;
    $scope.IsAuthenticated = $localStorage.IsAuthenticated;
}
```

I can only think of repeating this code to every controller which I do not want of course. What would be a better way?

Side note regarding security: all secure user actions are re-authenticated on the server so no harm is done when someone hacks the localstorage mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So actually you want to encapsulate a third party service to reduce your dependency on a third party library. Your third party library provides a service $localStorage with some properties you want to access. Here is one way to do so:

```
function YourAuthService($localStorage) {
  this.isAuthenticated = function () {
    return $localStorage.IsAuthenticated;
  }

  this.username = function() {
    return $localStorage.username;
  }
}
myApp.service('YourAuthService', YourAuthService);
```

That would create an injectable wrapper service that you can use like this:

```
function YourController(YourAuthService) {
  console.log("Current username=" + YourAuthService.username());
  console.log("Current isAuthenticated=" + YourAuthService.isAuthenticated());
}
```

Note how you don't need to know how your auth service figures out the data that you query. You just call the appropriate method and your auth service will do the rest. This could easily be adapted to other storage types.

If you want to create such a simple wrapper with less code then (in your special case) it could be done like this:

```
function YourAuthService($localStorage) {
  ["isAuthenticated", "username", "furtherProperty", "yadayada"].forEach(function(propertyName) {
    this[propertyName] = function() {
      return $localStorage[propertyName];
    }
  });
}
myApp.service('YourAuthService', YourAuthService);
```

Comment: Great help! Thank you very much, just tested successfully your first approach. Second did not work because ngStorage does not seem to support an array like storage mechanism. But I like the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two way to use the authentication data through out the app. First way you have already specified i.e. using a service, which is a good idea.

`$rootScope` should be avoided as this may result in unexpected behavior since this can be accessed anywhere by any module. So second step can be to mimic this `$rootScope` concept by creating a common controller like `BaseController` for a single page app and inject it to your `body` tag.

```
<body ng-controller="BaseController">
    <!-- different pages or views -->
    <div ng-controller="HomePageController" id="home-page"></div>
</body>
```

Now you can store your app wide common data like authentication data or anything other in the scope of `BaseController` which will be directly available to every other controllers scope since this will now be a parent controller scope of all controller.

Second approach can be more useful since you don't have to inject your service in every controller like in first step instead you can just use the `$scope` variable to access any data which is available in common controller since an scope of a controller is always being created with the parent scope.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Really interesting suggestion. Thank you for sharing this idea. Although I did not yet implement an SPA like site (I am still using separate HTML pages because some contain heavy weight JQuery controls/images, like the home page, which I do not want to spoil my core Angular pages with. But my next move will be completely removing the JQuery controls in favour of a full Angular site. Then your idea will become very handy.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for. Using a method in your UserService to reload your model data. The tutorial should explain it.

```
//In app-modules
app.run(['authService', function (authService) {
     authService.fillAuthData();
}]);

//In authService
var _fillAuthData = function () {

    var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
    if (authData)
    {
        _authentication.isAuth = true;
        _authentication.userName = authData.userName;
    }  
 }
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/784106/AngularJS-Token-Authentication-using-ASP-NET-Web-A